# При перемещении системы с HDD на SSD на жестком диске осталась копия

Tags: windows, hdd, ssd

Делал это с помощью Samsung Data Migration. В BIOS уже поменял приоритет загрузки на SSD. [image: Вот как это сейчас выглядит]

На диске Е новая копия, на диске С старая копия. Могу ли я спокойно форматировать диск С?

Comment: Я бы для надежности выдернул шлейф из жесткого диска и убедился что вся система точно без него работает

Comment: я бы тоже вытянул диск. Современные винды любят ставить систему на диск С всегда, так что есть подозрения, что может пойти что то не так